# What axiom of ZFC implies that "sets have no repeated elements"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

For example, the [axiom of pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_pairing) says:

Let $a$ be a set.

Let $b$ be a set.

If follows that the set $\{a,b\}$ exists.

This can be used to prove the existence of singletons, for instance, by setting $b := a$ (in the previous statement). Namely, the axiom of pairing implies the following:

Let $a$ be a set.

If follows that the set $\{a\}$ exists.

---

> This got me thinking. What ZFC axiom implies that, for any set $a$, the set $\{a,a\}$ equals the set $\{a\}$? Equivalently, what axiom of ZFC implies that the **sets** of ZFC don't behave like [**multisets**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)? (I suspect it's [**extensionality**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality), but I couldn't argue why. So, if it *is* extensionality, then I'm gonna need some convincing...)

Comment: $a\in\{a,a\}$; if $b\ne a$ then $b\notin\{a,a\}$.

Comment: Extensionality guarantees that sets do not behave like multisets in the sense that there cannot be two sets with the same elements (unlike multisets). But it does more: it ensures that formulas like $\{a,a\}$, $\{a\}$ or $\{a,b\}$ actually do unambiguously define sets (given $a$ and $b$, of course). But it does not tell us that the set $\{a\}$ is distinct from the multiset $\{a,a\}$: if we replaced the former by the latter (in a model of set theory, with the natural interpretation of $\in$), there would be no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [axiom of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality) is the statement:

> **Axiom of extensionality**.
> Let $A$ be a set.
> Let $B$ be a set.
> **IF** for every set $x$ $($ $x$ is in $A$ $ $ $ $ **IFF** $ $ $ $ $x$ is in $B$ $)$,
> **THEN** $A$ equals $B$.

We can use this to prove the "no repeated elements" property by setting $A := \{a,a\}$ and $B := \{a\}$ in the **axiom of extensionality**. So,

**Theorem**.  The set {a,a} equals the set $\{a\}$.
*Proof*. Since $\{a,a\}$ and $\{a\}$ are sets, they satisfy the hypotheses of the **axiom of extensionality**. So, they satisfy the conclusion.
This means that the sets $\{a,a\}$ and $\{a\}$ satisfy the implication:

> **IF** for every set $x$ $($ $x$ is in $\{a,a\}$ $ $ $ $ **IFF** $ $ $ $ $x$ is in $\{a\}$ $)$,
> **THEN** $\{a,a\}$ equals $\{a\}$.

So, if we can prove the antecedent

> $(*)$ for every set $x$ $($ $x$ is in $\{a,a\}$ $ $ $ $ **IFF** $ $ $ $ $x$ is in $\{a\}$ $)$,

then, by [modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens), it'll follow that

> $\{a,a\}$ equals $\{a\}$,

as desired.

We prove $(*)$ by verifying it for every element of $\{a,a\}$ and $\{a\}$.
The *key observation* is that: $a$ is in $\{a,a\}$ **and** $a$ is in $\{a\}$.

0. The 1st element of $\{a,a\}$ is $a$. By the [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) of [**IFF**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if), it holds that: $a$ is in $\{a,a\}$ $ $ **IFF** $ $ $a$ is in $\{a\}$.
1. The 2nd element of $\{a,a\}$ is $a$. By the [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) of [**IFF**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if), it holds that: $a$ is in $\{a,a\}$ $ $ **IFF** $ $ $a$ is in $\{a\}$.
2. The 1st element of $\{a\}$ is $a$. By the [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) of [**IFF**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if), it holds that: $a$ is in $\{a,a\}$ $ $ **IFF** $ $ $a$ is in $\{a\}$.
3. There are no other elements in $\{a,a\}$ or $\{a\}$.

This proves that: for every set $x$ $($ $x$ is in $\{a,a\}$ $ $ $ $ **IFF** $ $ $ $ $x$ is in $\{a\}$ $)$.

This proves that: $\{a,a\}$ equals $\{a\}$.

A similar argument proves that: $\{a,a,a\}$ equals $\{a\}$, and so on.

To extend this result to *every* finite number of $a$'s probably requires induction, which probably requires the axiom of infinity.

Answer (score 9):

It is indeed the extensionality axiom that is at play here.

We have

$$\forall x (x \in A \iff x \in B)$$ where $A = \{a,a\}$ and $B=\{a\}$ as for both sets $A$ and $B$, $x$ belongs to one of those set if and only if $x=a$.

Therefore $A=B$ by entensionality.

Comment: A bit too terse for me. Can you add more verbiage?

Comment: Can you point to the sentence(s) that is(are) to terse?

Comment: Everything is! You don't even define extensionality.

Comment: But I'll try. You say "We have $\forall x ...$". Why do we have that? Where did it come from? Extensionality? Why? Why $A = \{a,a\}$ and $B = \{a\}$? Is it a hypothesis? You don't say it is. What do you mean "as for both sets $A$ and $B$"? Why "$x$ belongs to one of those sets if and only if $x = a$"? Then you say "Therefore...". Why "therefore"? Why does that follow from the previous part? I cannot see the logical flow of the proof: the hypotheses, the intermediate steps, and the conclusion, and a careful explanation of why each part follows from the previous.

Comment: I won't define extensionality as you just have to look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality)!

Comment: Eg. when I quote the axiom of pairing, I don't assume the reader remembers the exact logical form of the statement (hypotheses and conclusion) even though most probably will, so I include it as a courtesy (using symbols only when they make the reading easier). In a rigorous proof, with even more reason, you'd be expected to be more careful and explicit about these things. Carefully defining in a reader-friendly way the main results you use (in this case, Extensionality), and then carefully explaining all the steps. You know, a somewhat formal proof that's more explicit and easier to follow.

Comment: If you don't wanna define Extensionality for your readers, that's fine, but I cannot follow anything else in the argument. =(

Comment: What is the background of your question? Are you studying set theory at least at the beginner level?

Comment: I am studying it (since I formulated the question in the first place).

Comment: In the Wikipedia page, $x$ in your answer is in capital in that page which denotes set. So, set X is an element of set A? What does it mean?